# How would I pass and entry's field value to an include?

Tags: variable, include

I have this:

```
{% include "partials/includes/page-header" with { 'title' : '{{ entry.heading }}' } %}
```

But it seems that nothing I do will actually pass `{{ entry.heading }}` as 'title' in the include.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll never need to put Twig tags within other Twig tags... Try it like this:

```
{% include "partials/includes/page-header" with { 'title' : entry.heading } %}
```